# How to connect firebase to C# Windows based app

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to connect my C# windows based app to firebase realtime database. Is there any convenient library to do the same? or is there any better method to do so?

Answer (score 5):

From this link [here](https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-c-library-5c342989ad18) you can say that [FirebaseDatabase.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) is better than another older library like `FireSharp` and `FirebaseSharp` :

They both have their imperfections, specifically related to realtime streaming.

For example, when we subscribe to a location, and a change happens to some nested node, `FireSharp` won’t correctly pair it with the top level entity and will only return the path and data as a string. We want the deserialization to be automatic.

`FirebaseSharp‘s` streaming implementation is even more unfortunate — at first, it fetches everything from a given location (even when we specify filtering options) and does the filtering locally. This is obviously not usable when there are thousands of items.

Also, neither of them targets Universal Windows Platform.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase for Windows is not release ready yet. We have a [C++ library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup) and a [C# library](https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-c-library-5c342989ad18) for firebase and both of them support Windows. But a quick look at the [support pages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup#available-libraries) will show you that Firebase is only supported for Android, iOS and Web. The desktop version of Firebase API's is a beta feature and is not recommended for shipping. You can integrate it but you are not supposed to ship it. I would recommend going through Firebase alternatives instead of shipping your product with Firebase and waiting for the desktop version to be out of beta for you to ship it.

Answer (score 2):

Following the instruction [here](https://5minuteshack.blogspot.com/2021/07/quickly-setup-firebase-for-net-c.html).

It might help you.

He's using Google.Cloud.Storage and Google.Cloud.Firestore to make connect and retrieve data from collection.